# How can I CLOSE showOptionDialog?

Tags: java

One of my codes in Java is like below. When I first click 'No', the showOptionDialog pops up again asking me same question 'Yes' or 'No'. I click 'No' and it shows up again. Then when I click 'No' at third time, it will dispose itself. Though I haven't implemented any code for 'No' in the below code. Can you see any error in the code please?

```
mainFrame.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {

    public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent windowEvent) {
        Object[] options = {"Yes", "No"};

    int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(mainFrame,"Do you really want to close iDiary?","Exit",
    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
    JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE,null,options,options[1]);

    if(n==0)
    {
        System.out.println(n++);
        System.exit(1);
    }
   }
 );
```

**Note**
In the JFrame called mainFrame has JTabbedPane tab = new JTabbedPane(); in it. There are 3 tabs in the mainFrame. I strongly assume that the 3 tabs are related to popping up three times. Any suggestion so it will only pops up once only?

Comment: Does it throw a exception or is it a logic error that you are explaining?

Comment: Unrelated, But use `showConfirmDialog` if you only want a yes, no option.

Comment: i tried your code and it is closed after the first time clicking No/Yes button.

Comment: Please post [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for help resolving the issue

Comment: Your problem is not on the code you show, it merely shows the dialog one time.

Comment: Also, couldn't help but notice your code would not compile as you are missing a `}` before your closing parenthesis. Are you running the same code you are trying to compile ?

Comment: My crystal ball says that you are invoking this code 3 times, so that you are adding 3 instances of this `WindowAdapter` to your `mainFrame` instance. To avoid this, just make sure that this line, starting with `mainFrame.addWindowListener...`, is only invoked **once**.